# How can I add new record in database using hibernate with JBOSS Tool?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, pojo, jboss-tools

I am using Eclipse and JBOSS Tool to generate hibernate class from MySQL.
The salary table have composite key, one is FK(userId), one is AUTO_INCREMENT. So JBOSS Tool generated Salary and User class, it also generated SalaryId class.
I have added cascade in getSalaries method of User class, but when I tried to save the new user, I always get the exception:
**org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails**

Does anyone have any idea to help me solve this problem? Thanks all~

Below are my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `salary` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `comingDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`userId`),
 KEY `userId` (`userId`)
)
```

Below are my generated class:
[User class]

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", catalog = "lab")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private Set<Salary> salaries = new HashSet<Salary>(0);

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String password, String email, Set<Salary> salaries) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.salaries = salaries;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Salary> getSalaries() {
        return this.salaries;
    }
    public void setSalaries(Set<Salary> salaries) {
        this.salaries = salaries;
    }
}
```

[Salary class]

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "salary", catalog = "lab")
public class Salary implements java.io.Serializable {

    private SalaryId id;
    private User user;
    private int amount;
    private Date comingDate;

    public Salary() {
    }

public Salary(SalaryId id, User user, int amount) {
        this.id = id;
        this.user = user;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public Salary(SalaryId id, User user, int amount, Date comingDate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.user = user;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.comingDate = comingDate;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "userId", column = @Column(name = "userId", nullable = false)) })
    public SalaryId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(SalaryId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Column(name = "amount", nullable = false)
    public int getAmount() {
        return this.amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "comingDate", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getComingDate() {
        return this.comingDate;
    }

    public void setComingDate(Date comingDate) {
        this.comingDate = comingDate;
    }
}
```

Below is auto generated by JBOSS Tool:

[SalaryId class]

```
@Embeddable
public class SalaryId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int id;
    private int userId;

    public SalaryId() {
    }

    public SalaryId(int id, int userId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "userId", nullable = false)
    public int getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if ((this == other))
            return true;
        if ((other == null))
            return false;
        if (!(other instanceof SalaryId))
            return false;
        SalaryId castOther = (SalaryId) other;

        return (this.getId() == castOther.getId())
                && (this.getUserId() == castOther.getUserId());
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;

        result = 37 * result + this.getId();
        result = 37 * result + this.getUserId();
        return result;
    }
}
```

[Main class]

```
transaction = session.beginTransaction();
SalaryId salaryId = new SalaryId();
Set<Salary> salaries = new HashSet<Salary>();

User user = new User();
user.setName("JW");
user.setPassword("123456");
user.setEmail("jjj@jj.cc");

salaries.add(new Salary(salaryId, user, 10000));
user.setSalaries(salaries);

session.save(user);

transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to do like this:

```
transaction = session.beginTransaction();
SalaryId salaryId = new SalaryId();
Set<Salary> salaries = new HashSet<Salary>();

User user = new User();
user.setName("JW");
user.setPassword("123456");
user.setEmail("jjj@jj.cc");

session.save(user);

salaries.add(new Salary(salaryId, user, 10000));
//user.setSalaries(salaries);

transaction.commit();
```

Comment: This will only save the `user` record not it's salary because hibernate has no idea that these objects exist if you don't add them to the collection.